# Get every line with string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to read lines from a txt file and return every line that has a certain string on it. In this case I'm looking for "1992"

alt.txt

```
1223 abcd
1992 dcba
1992 asda
```

file.php

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, $str) {
    $lines = file($fileName);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
            return $line;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I run the php, I get "1992 dcba" as the return, when I want to receive an array with each line. $line[0] would be "1992 dcba" and $line[1] would be "1992 asda". How could I do this?

Comment: Well u already have your answer. `$lines` is that array actualy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an array of all the valid results and return that, rather than simply returning the first result

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, $str) {
    $results = array();
    $lines = file($fileName);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
            $results[] = $line;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I now get, say, the second in the array while using the function? I tried doing `getLineWithString('alt.txt', $match_id)[1]` but that just gave me an error about an unexpected `[`.

Comment: To use array dereferencing, as your comment asks, you need PHP 5.4 or above (which you really should be doing anyway as all earlier versions are unsupported)

Answer (score 4):

Another way using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

```
$lines = file('alt.txt');
$results = preg_grep("/1992/", $lines);
```

`preg_grep` will preserve the original keys in the returned array. If you don't want that add the following to reindex the returned array

```
$results = array_values($results);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are currently doing is returning as soon as it finds a particular string. What you want to do is put the line into an array and return the array. So you would get the following:

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, $str) {
    $lines = file($fileName);
    $returnLines = array();

    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
            $returnLines[] = $line;
        }
    }
    return count($returnLines) > 0 ? $returnLines : -1;
}
```

I've added a single line if statement on the return so you will still return -1 if nothing was added.